# "Commit" vs. "commitment" vs. "committing" in computer-related texts

Tags: word-choice

Let’s suppose we have the following excerpt:

1. how the target DB engine handles data **commitment**
2. how the target DB engine handles data **commit**
3. how the target DB engine handles data **committing**

Which of those three variants is correct?

I'm confused by *commit* as a noun because no dictionary claims it is. But it is used pretty often as a noun in the computer-related texts.

Comment: As far as **commit** goes, I think you've answered it yourself! It's not recognised by dictionaries as a noun, but it is used (and recognised) as one in certain circles. Hence no2 is not "correct", but it *is* perfectly reasonable to use it in situations where it will be widely recognised.

Comment: @AndyT, what about other variants. Are they correct?

Comment: One needs to understand that "commit" as a feature (and therefore a noun) of software systems has many variations over it's long history, by many different companies.  Though there is a "core" terminology that all will understand, the different companies are likely to use different variations of the word (in part due to who won when the programmers duked it out with the writers and editors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [**commitment**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commitment) has many definitions, including "the act of committing" and "the state of being committed". But "how the target DB engine handles data **commitment**" doesn't sound natural to me. Consider as an alternative phrase "the commitment of the crime was late on a Saturday night" - this sounds similarly wrong to my ear. So I don't like Option 1, though I can't prove that it is incorrect.
2. [**commit**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/commit) is apparently not a noun. However it is, as you point out, frequently used as one in the computing world. So Option 2 is not grammatically correct, but it sounds perfectly normal to my ear, and would probably be widely accepted in a computing environment.
3. Option 3 is getting beyond my knowledge of theoretical grammar. It sounds wrong to me. But, considering an equivalent phrase: "Let's see how Steve handles John beating him at snooker", it sounds fine. So probably Option 3 is completely grammatically correct.

So, what would I do? I'd go for a completely different noun derived from *commit* - I would use [**committal**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/committal).

> how the target DB engine handles data **committal**

*All links courtesy of dictionary.reference.com*

Comment: In computerese, "commit" is both a noun and a verb.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a database company for three years and I most frequently heard the word used as a noun, something like this:

- "The database will confirm a commit by doing X"
- "When talking about how the database does commits"

In this case, "a commit" is understood to be a piece of data that has been written to memory/disk or similar.  Hence I would say that your second option would become

- How the target DB engine handles a data commit (singular)
- how the target DB engine handles data commits (plural)

The verb form which you have listed in 1 and 3 was not something I heard as often, but when I did hear it used, it was usually in the third form you listed above, that is: "committing".  I don't think I have ever heard anyone use the first version you listed (commitment) in conversation.

Personally, I think that the reason it sounds odd to me is simply because commitment is a term more frequently used to describe the human capability to commit to a task, person, job rather than a technical term.  However, in the right context I would have no problem understanding the terms as it pertains to databases.

With that anecdotal, personal evidence out of the way, I will note that searching for "data committing" and "data commitment" in a database context in Google returns plenty of relevant results.  In fact data commitment returns twice the number of results.  Hence both terms are clearly used as verbs and are acceptable as such.

Comment: The "official" term for the "commit" feature of a data base system is often/usually "commitment control".  Programmers avoid it, however, because they can never remember whether it's "commitment" or "committment".

Answer (score 1):

In computer terms, a commit is a command. It says take all the edits I have been doing and make them permanent. But you do not commit something, you *do a commit*. It's a key distinction. The verb is not "to commit." It's "to do a commit."

If you are describing what happens behind the scenes when you use the commit command, you can talk about *committing* data.

Comment: I've been a programmer for nearly 50 years, and I have definitely heard "commit" used as a verb, as in "commit the data".  Terms like "do a commit" are said, to a lesser degree, but are a bit weird to my ear.

Comment: @Hot Licks I can only count 25 years of programming, but the commit in your example, "commit the data," is an imperative, which underscores that commit is a command. You do a commit. You perform a commit. You issue a commit. You schedule a commit. To me, the nature of the commit command makes it the object of the verb, not the verb itself.

Comment: How is "commit the data" not using "commit" as a verb??

Comment: @Hot Licks As I noted, it's an imperative, which is by definition, a verb. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood

Comment: I'm confused.  You're saying that, because "commit" *might* be used as an "imperative", one can't write "After step xyz the program commits the changes to the data base"?  Or, "I will commit the changes to that code after the review is complete"?

Comment: Mohair is correct in his examples of how you use the word and how you don't use the word in the software world.  Hot Licks -- it's true that Mohair is giving a rationale that doesn't make any sense (you are correct that the verb need not be in the imperative mood), but please, relax, what you're doing here is coming across as nitpicking -- it's not becoming.

Comment: @aparente001 - If it's wrong, it's wrong.  Mohair said "The verb is not 'to commit.' It's 'to do a commit.' "  That's wrong.  Either form is valid.

Comment: @HotLicks - I take it your subset of the software world employs both forms interchangeably.  Good to know!

Comment: @aparente001 - It may well be that a particular software product sticks with one form or the other in its documentation, but there are easily a thousand different software products that have some sort of commitment control, and they do not all use precisely the same terminology.